# Postgresql on my Linux AWS says active(exited)

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-ec2

I have been using postgresql to connect my python program into the db and read and write data
Yesterday onwards it's not connecting and i run `sudo systemctl status postgresql` and this is the result:

```
 postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2023-12-18 04:52:59 UTC; 39min ago
    Process: 18943 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 18943 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms
```

I need to get this up and running.

I tried restarting but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That's what systemd says about services that get started by running a command that exits (probably `pg_ctl` in your case; see the service file). That status has nothing to do with the question if PostgreSQL is actually running or not.

Use `pg_isready` to see if the server is actually running, or look for the running processes with a command like

```bash
ps -f -u postgres
```